# Combining sed from awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a text file which contains multiple sections and I want to change content present inside one of those sections (## Screenshots ## section in my case) and leave the other sections untouched.

Part of the file looks like

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

1. This is the first line

2. There could be blank lines like the one above and below.

3. Lines could contain special characters like ( # $ % etc and even quotes ""'` etc
5. Lines numbers need not be sequential.
4. Lines numbers could be in any order


## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

and it should be modified to

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

![](screeshot-1.png)
This is the first line

![](screeshot-2.png)
There could be blank lines like the one above and below.

![](screeshot-3.png)
Lines could contain special characters like ( # $ % etc and even quotes ""'` etc
![](screeshot-5.png)
Lines numbers need not be sequential.
![](screeshot-4.png)
Lines numbers could be in any order

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

I have the following script to do it.

```
awk '/^## Screenshots ##/ {f="screenshot.md";print > f;next} 
    f=="screenshot.md" && /^##/ {f="after_screenshot.md"} 
    {print > f}' f=before_screenshot.md readme.md

sed "/^[0-9]/s/\(^[0-9]*\)./\!\[\](screeshot-\1.png)\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/" screenshot.md > processed-screenshots.md

cat before-screeshots.md processed-screenshots.md after-screenshots.md > readme.md
```

It works. But as you can see it is quite ugly and also there is this unneeded step where I create multiple temp files.

I was trying to see if I can improve this and one idea that came to me was that if I can somehow call `sed` from `awk`, then I can get away from creating temp files.

So my question is how I can call `sed` from `awk`? If not is there a way by which I can improve this script and get away from creating those temp files.

Kindly note that I want this script to work both in Ubuntu and mac. Thanks.

**Update**:

One clarification. It is not necessary that the different sections will always be present in the same order. In the above example screenshots is followed by changelog, but could change. The only thing that we know is that the next section will also start with `##`

**Update 2**:

Another clarification. There could be blank lines in the screenshot section and the lines are not always 2 words. Updated the example file.

My sincere apologies for not explaining all the corner cases before hand.

Comment: `Calling sed from awk` no.. we don't do that here!

Comment: @sudo_O Agreed. Changed the title :)

Comment: Don't forget to update your expected output to match your new input.

Comment: @Sudar in the expected output, the `line 1,2,3` should be same as the input file (screeenshot section) or they should be really `line 1, 2, 3...`?

Comment: @Kent Sorry ket, I am not sure if I understand your question. Do you mean whether the line numbers will be in order?

Comment: @Sudar oh, when I read my comment twice, it was not so clear. sorry. just check the EDIT in my answer, if the output is what you want. or you just want the exact text `line 1, line 2...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {                 # Set the field separator to a . for picking up line num
    FS="."
}
/^##/ {                 # If we hit the a new section stop
    flag = 0
}
flag && $1~/^[0-9]+/ {  # If the the flag is set and starts with number add text
    print "![](screeshot-" $1 ".png)"
    sub(/^[0-9]+ /,"")  # Remove the leading line number (no limit on fields)
}
/^## Screenshots ##$/ { # If we hit the screenshot section start
    flag=1
}
{                       # Print all the lines in the file
        print
}
```

Save this to a file, say `f.awk` *(something more descriptive perhaps)* and run like:

```
$ awk -f f.awk file
```

Outputs:

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

![](screeshot-1.png)
This is the first line

![](screeshot-2.png)
There could be blank lines like the one above and below.

![](screeshot-3.png)
Lines could contain special characters like ( # $ % etc and even quotes ""'` etc
![](screeshot-5.png)
Lines numbers need not be sequential.
![](screeshot-4.png)
Lines numbers could be in any order


## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

Comment: I specially like the `{f=0}NF` to check if the line is empty or not.

Comment: It works except for one small thing. It was trying to add screenshot-x.png to blank lines as well inside ##screenshots section. I replaced `NF && flag {`   with `NF && flag && $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {` and it fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -r '/## Screenshots ##/,/## Changelog ##/{s/^([0-9]+)\. (.*)/![](screenshot-\1.png)\n\2/g}' yourfile
```

If you don't have a `-r` option,

```
sed '/## Screenshots ##/,/## Changelog ##/{s/^\([0-9]\+\)\. \(.*\)/![]\(screenshot-\1.png\)\n\2/g}' yourfile
```

Comment: `-r` option is not available in mac version of sed

Answer (score 2):

This one liner should work for your problem (with your update)

```
awk '/^## Screen/{p=1;print;next}p&&/^##/{p=0}p&&$0{print "![](screenshot-"++i".png)";$0=$2FS$3}7' file
```

output:

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

![](screenshot-1.png)
line 1
![](screenshot-2.png)
line 2
![](screenshot-3.png)
line 3
![](screenshot-4.png)
line 4

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

**EDIT** for the new example:

```
awk '/^## Screen/{p=1;print;next}p&&/^##/{p=0}p&&$0{print "![](screenshot-"++i".png)";sub(/^\S* /,"")}7' file
```

outputs:

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

![](screenshot-1.png)
This is the first line

![](screenshot-2.png)
There could be blank lines like the one above and below.

![](screenshot-3.png)
Lines could contain special characters like ( # $ % etc and even quotes ""'` etc
![](screenshot-4.png)
line 4

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

Comment: `There could be blank lines in the screenshot section and the lines are not always 2 words. Updated the example file.`

Comment: @Kent This is the output I want. But when I run your script (in mac) the blank lines inside screenshot section also gets replaced. Also the number present in screenshot-x.ping, is the number present at the beginning of the line, not the line number. Also Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @Sudar do you have gawk? try this line: `awk '/^## Screen/{p=1;print;next}p&&/^##/{p=0}p&&!/^\s*$/{print "![](screenshot-"++i".png)";sub(/^\S* /,"")}7' file'`